# How to execute an AJAX event on a CheckBoxMultipleChoice in WicketTester

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I'm using Wicket 6.20.0's `CheckBoxMultipleChoice` and leveraging AJAX functionality by adding a `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`.

This is working as required. However, using `WicketTester` to test the functionality of `CheckBoxMultipleChoice` seems impossible.

When I use `WicketTester`'s `debugComponentTrees()` the only path for the `CheckBoxMultipleChoice` is its direct path, I.E. there are no child `CheckBox` objects or similar I can obtain to execute AJAX events on.

How can I execute an AJAX event, such as clicking one of the check boxes, using `WicketTester`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CheckBoxMultipleChoice is an "optimized" form component, i.e. it uses String concatenation to create its "children" - the check boxes. If it was using CheckBox components then it would lead to bigger component tree and more memory consumption.

To test it with WicketTester you just need to set the request parameter with all selected values:

```
tester.getRequest().addParameter(cbmc.getInputName(), "value1");
tester.getRequest().addParameter(cbmc.getInputName(), "value2");
// ...
tester.executeAjaxEvent(cbmc, "click");
// assert
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this looks really promising, although, which check box would be clicked when `tester.executeAjaxEvent(cbmc, "click")` is called?

Comment: `tester.executeAjaxEvent(cbmc, "click")` simulates a click on checkbox `value2` where `value1` is already selected, i.e. clicked previously. If you need to do it one by one then you need several `tester.executeAjaxEvent(cbmc, "click")` calls, each with its respective `#addParameter(...)` call.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've got this working but now still struggle to test anything other than the underlying model. How would you test, say, is the checkboxes were enabled / disabled?

Comment: For such kind of tests you need something like Selenium/WebDriver or like Gym.js (http://wicketinaction.com/2012/11/javascript-based-functional-testing/). WicketTester can only assert state at the server and produced HTML. It cannot do assertions with JavaScript.